# Cannot deploy django on Apache with mod-wsgi

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, mod-wsgi

I have been working on a Django app that I am ready to move to the production server. I have Apache and mod_wsgi installed and I used a test to check to see that it all works, and it does. But now I am having problems getting it to work with Django.

I have created the wsgi.py file:

```
import os
import os.path
import sys


sys.path.append('/var/www/html/mideastinfo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/bin/mideastinfo')
#os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = 'path to a directory for egg cache'
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mideastinfo.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandlers()
```

And I have the http.conf point to it via WGSIScriptAlias. It's not working, I know it has to do with the sys.path, I am not sure what to do.

I had a development environment in which I did all the build. Then, I installed all the project dependencies onto the server user pip and a requirements.txt. Then, I moved my project files over. But I think I am getting all the mapping and pathing wrong. Any ideas? I feel like I am one step away from being done with this.

Comment: application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandlers()
[Mon Sep 29 19:13:07 2014] [error] [client 157.55.39.217] AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'WSGIHandlers'

Comment: What happens when you >python manage.py shell and import django.core.handlers.wsgi ?

Comment: nothing, no repsonse

Comment: and what are you putting on 'PATH TO YOUR PROJECT ROOT'? Is your project inside /var/www/html/mideastinfo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/bin/mideastinfo? Where did you place wsgi.py?

Comment: Yes, what you quoted is what I have as path to project root. I think that is the problem. the wsgi.py file is at var/www/html/wsgi.py

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62148/discussion-between-andre-teixeira-and-bamabacho).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will share how I've configured a simple example:

```
import os,sys
apache_configuration = os.path.dirname(__file__)
project = os.path.dirname(apache_configuration)
workspace = os.path.dirname(project)
sys.path.append(workspace)
sys.path.append('PATH TO YOUR PROJECT ROOT')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mideastinfo.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

On your VirtualHost directive on Apache config you must have:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /PATH/TO/YOUR/.wsgi
```

Example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ErrorLog /home/user/logs/error.log
    ...
    WSGIScriptAlias / /PATH/TO/YOUR/.wsgi
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: This helped. I moved things around and tightened up the project path. Also, I realized that for my version the last two lines are depracated, and so I used from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()